# SESSION ERROR - Permisison Denied (13)

Tags: php, session

I am geting the following error in the Log Files from a Web App (OpenCart). Has anyone seen this? Or can I just ignore this "somewhat known bug"? I tried following other posts regarding this specific error, without success:

> PHP Notice:  session_start(): ps_files_cleanup_dir: opendir(/var/lib/php/session) failed: Permission denied (13)

In that dedicate server's session folder, I see:

```
-rw------- 1 apache apache  48 Mar  5 19:21 sess_0pl62elpgn43rjakfh6em2v2n5
-rw------- 1 apache apache  48 Mar  5 19:33 sess_2vo41urqek50ef9nl1429879i3
-rw------- 1 apache apache 125 Mar  5 18:59 sess_35goisejg3asq4n4hntcsgofu6
-rw------- 1 apache apache  48 Mar  5 19:16 sess_4cgkdiqfqgfgje356uoem0r7s3
-rw------- 1 apache apache  48 Mar  5 19:33 sess_5ji1i4kppt6ara43v8jdflcgh6
-rw------- 1 apache apache  48 Mar  5 19:34 sess_5sbl2o6ndpphh8jqogrb12v6j1
  .
  .
```

LAMP, CentOS 5, PHP 5.2

Comment: Folder permission is wrong and server cannot read it.

Comment: Having the same issue on a CentOS dedicated server, did you ever figure out what the issue was?

Answer (score 20):

For fixing the  ***ps_files_cleanup_dir: opendir(/var/lib/php/sessions) failed: Permission denied***  issue I recommend the following two things:

1. To grant the write access rights for this particular folder (/var/lib/php/sessions) to the operating system.

   **$ sudo chmod 755 /var/lib/php/sessions**
2. Another good solution is to set a custom location (which the PHP interpreter can write the session files to) for the session folder with the session.save-path in php.ini.

**Note**: Disabling the PHP’s session garbage collector with the session.gc_probability=0 PHP setting is not a good solution, because you will have a lot of orphaned session files in the session folder, and it will waste the disk space and slow down your server.

Comment: This looks like a bad idea because it will allow all login users to access the `sessions` directory. It creates a serious security risk in some situations. On Debian and Ubuntu at least, there is a root `cron` job to clean up the directory regularly, so `session.gc_probability=0` is actually a good way to take care of the situation there.

Answer (score 11):

If your httpd server user/group are www-data.www-data then change:

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/lib/php/sessions
```

This should give httpd server ownership of this directory.

Comment: thank you very mych